# Add item in allow list of the AVG or Norton antivirus using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, operating-system, antivirus

Is it possible to allow or restrict items using c# asp.net?

Comment: Well that would be a *serious security vulnerability*, you may do it with a noble intention but then there are many in waiting for such an exploit and unleash ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ASP.Net you can't modify client's system resources.  I am not sure you if can do that using a desktop application with C#

Comment: What about Destop App like WPF/Winforms?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal,  not sure, possibly not

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal - Contact AVG and Norton and ask them this question.  If it was possible the programs would have to support it.  Of course considering the security implementation if either actually do support this you shouldn't use their products.